# OData POST entity creation with expand

Tags: post, odata, expand

I'm attempting to create an instance of an entity and two child entities at the same time.

If I post the following JSON to the /user_objects resource it happily creates the parent user_object entity and the linked User_object_attribute entity. The only problem is that I can't seem to expand the result set to include the new user_object_attribute so I effectively have the most uptodate version of the user_object but I have to then go and read from the OData service i.e. another server hit in order to retrieve the user_object_attributes.

Upon returning I have the id that would go neatly into the child user_object_attribute object but what if the child had a further server-side generated field like created_date? Then I still have to hit the OData repo again?

I've tried the correct $expand query ?$expand=user_objects_attributes and while the creation succeeds I still am not returned the expanded result set.

Would anyone have any idea if this is possible? Or is it a case that it isn't because hte only way to do it would be to return all the child user_object_attributes?

```
{
   "annotator_id":1,
   "content_type":"content_type",
   "created_date":"2013-02-15T17:20:09.191",
   "guid":"GUID",
   "size_kb":100,
   "title":"Title",
   "updated_date":null,
   "url":"URL",
   "user_object_id":0,
   "user_objects_attributes":[
      {
         "attribute_id":0,
         "name":"name191",
         "user_object_id":0,
         "value":"value191"
      }
   ]
}
```

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the OData V3 specification [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/E/95EF66AF-9026-4BB0-A41D-A4F81802D92C/%5BMS-ODATA%5D.pdf):

> In version 1.0 and version 2.0, if the insert succeeds in full, the
>   server MUST return a response with a 201 (Created) status code and a
>   response body that conforms to the syntax specified in InsertEntity
>   Request (section 2.2.7.1.1). The response body MUST contain the values
>   of the inserted resource after the server has executed all its
>   server-specific data processing rules (validation, and so on). The
>   server MAY alter the values of the resource received from the client
>   before the resource is inserted on the server.
>
> In version 3.0, the response MAY have a 204 status code, as specified
>   in [RFC2616], based on the client preference (see Prefer (section
>   2.2.5.9)) on the InsertEntity Request.

Not super clear what a server should do... return just the top level created entity, or that entity and all of it's expanded links as well.

I'm not surprised that $expand would have no effect on POST (or any CUD requests). WCF DS probably ignores it if it isn't a query. And by the spec, this is probably correct.

Quite frankly, I think with WCF DS Server you can't get anything else back. In V3 you either get a 201 with your entity (only), or a 204 no content if you specify the header saying that you want no content.

Whether that is OData compliant or not... not totally sure :-). Regardless, I don't think you can get what you want on the WCF DS stack at this point in time.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to return navigation properties after a `POST` to create a new entity using OData v4's `$expand` query option without issues.

Make sure your method is decorated with `[EnableQuery]` and you call `Include` with the name of the navigation property.

For example:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult Post(user_object user)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
    }

    this.db.user_objects.Add(user);
    this.db.SaveChanges();

    user = this.db.user_objects.Include("user_objects_attributes").Single(x => x.user_object_id == user.user_object_id));

    return this.Created(user);
}
```

The `POST` URL query string should include `?$expand=user_objects_attributes`.

Also see:
https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/356